# Angular 7 Form validation for dynamic field

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular7, angular-forms

My form contains 2 checkboxes, If i select one of the checkboxes it will populate one textbox (child question). In my scenario, I have 2 checkboxes and 2 text boxes and one submit button. both the text boxes are mandatory field.

If the user submits the form without entering textbox it should show the error message.

Lets assume

> User selects the first checkbox, so textbox 1 will populate. then user
>   fills the textbox1 and hits submit button, form gets submitted fine.

In my scenario.

> User selects the second checkbox after submitting the form, so the
>   child question comes with error message. but i am expect the second
>   textbox error message should come after hit the submit button again.

Please see the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-et9uww) for better understanding.

Comment: Please ask a clear question.  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: please try these steps in stackblitz   1. select first checkbox then fill textbox and hit submitt button. again select second checkbox then the textbox will come with error message but i don't want that error message on time of render the textbox.

Comment: if user hit submit button second time without entering the textbox then only the error message should come

Answer (score 0):

It is showing the message because the form has been already submitted and based upon the html condition it is showing the error message before submission.

Once the form is submitted you can access the `submit` attribute of the angular form using `ViewChild` and you can make it as `false`. Hope this solves your issues

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  title = 'InputDirective';

  checkbox_a:boolean;
  checkbox_b:boolean;
  textbox1:string;
  textbox2:string;
  @ViewChild("angularForm", {static: false}) public angularForm: any;

  onSubmit() {
    alert('form submitted success..');
    this.angularForm.submitted = false;
  }

}
```

Stacblitz link --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjm3lq